# recursive associations many to many and primary keys and foreign keys

Tags: sql

Hi i have ER scheme with an recursive associations many to many with primary keys for example:

```
        ______(0,N)_________
 ID    |     base            \
  \course                  preparatory
       |___advanced_________/
             (1,N)
```

where course is entity and preparatory is association nad course have ID primary key.

My question is:
course have ID primary key but, preparatory association?

I suppose that  preparatory association have base and advanced primary keys and ID_course foreign key:

```
course       primary key:ID
preparatory  primary key:base,advanced,ID_course  foreign key:ID_course
```

is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model, I assume that `preparatory` represents all the courses that are required to be completed because you can start the principal course.

In that case you are correct, you will need a separate table to manage the multiple IDs, I would suggest something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Course(
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT Course_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Preparatory(
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   Advanced_CourseID INT NOT NULL,
   Required_CourseID INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT Preparatory_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   CONSTRAINT Preparatory_Advanced_Course_ID_FK
              FOREIGN KEY (Advanced_CourseID)
              REFERENCES Course (ID),
   CONSTRAINT Preparatory_Required_Course_ID_FK
              FOREIGN KEY (Required_CourseID)
              REFERENCES Course (ID)
);
```

The expectation is that `Advanced_CourseID` represents the princial singular reference and there will be unique `Required_CourseID` for each `Advanced_CourseID`.

To further describe this I would suggest declaring a unique index on this relationship to enforce the desired structural integrity:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY Preparatory_Advanced_Required_Course_ID_UX
ON Preparatory(Advanced_CourseID,Advanced_CourseID);

ALTER TABLE Preparatory
ADD CONSTRAINT Unique_Preparatory_Advanced_Required_Course_ID
UNIQUE USING INDEX Preparatory_Advanced_Required_Course_ID_UX;
```